# ICB industrial classification code for companies

Tags: python, finance

I need ICB Industrial classification code for US stock companies, I know stocks listed in the Nasdaq index are provided with this classification code, I search but did not find any source which I can download or scrape ICB code for companies. please, if you have any information about this let me know.
In summary, I need various companies' industry classification codes in different systems of classification (like ICB, GICs, ...), I did not find any source which provides ICB codes for listed companies in the US.

Comment: Question needs some code
Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I don't think there is a list anywhere (from my own search).  I found all of the codes for the sectors and sub sectors, but not for each individual company.  You will either need to use Bloomberg (or another software), or pay for it from somewhere I think.